# Let us assume that NP is not equal to P. Are there decision problems such that it is known that they can only be answered by brute force?

Tags: lo.logic

For example, in principle, it seems possible that that there is a class H
of graphs (perhaps satisfying some specific conditions) such that, for any
G in H, the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle in G can only be decided
by brute force.

Comment: "Can only be decided by brute force" seems like too vague of a property for this question to be answerable.

Comment: I mean that it is possible to find the right answer only by examining all the possibilities one by one.

Comment: It's not well-defined what "possibilities" mean. Take Hamiltonian cycles, for example. Is a "possibility" any permutation of vertices of your graph? Then no, there are always trivial improvements over the algorithm that checks all of those possibilities, for example you could directly enumerate all permutations where the first pair of vertices is already known to be an edge (by enumerating all edges and then a permutation on the remaining vertices).

Comment: Similarly with problems like 3SAT. Instead of trying *all* assignments of variables, it suffices to enumerate only assignments which satisfy the first clause already. Of course, in both cases, we would still call the resulting algorithm a brute force algorithm, but the point is that it's more of a "you know it when you see it" type thing, and it's not clear how to formalize the notion.

Comment: Thank you, you seem to be right: indeed, a brute force algorithm can often
be slightly improved remaining at the same time a brute force algorithm.
Nevertheless, just the meaningfulness of this statement shows that my question
is a "you know what I mean" type of question so I hope someone helps me to
reformulate it into an exact one.

Comment: See https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/exact-algorithms-for-np-hard-problems-a-survey

Comment: Perhaps you'd be satisfied by a problem in NP where it is known that there is a known lower bound for the solution time that is exponential in $n$ (the size of the problem).
Of course if such a problem and lower bound were known, that would prove $P \ne NP$.  I realize you're assuming $P \ne NP$, but that does not imply $P \ne NP$ is provable.  I think a proof that $P \ne NP$ implies $P \ne NP$ provable would be big news, so it's very unlikely that this is currently known.

Comment: Maybe you would be interested in the "strong exponential time hypothesis"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis This is a strengthening of $P \neq NP$ which is a bit hard to state precisely, but which implies lower bounds for many NP-complete problems which are of the form $(\text{runtime of brute search})^{1-o(1)}$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer it is worth mentioning that "fine-grained complexity" is perhaps a better term to search on, and the area does more than work with NP-complete problems, i.e. one may use some assumption that a P problem takes $O(n^k)$ time to show that known algorithms for other P problems are roughly optimal.

Comment: @CraigFeinstein Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Gyorgy, you should also read Impagliazzo's "Five Worlds" paper, http://www-cse.ucsd.edu/~russell/average.ps .  P!=NP means there is no P-time algorithm for SAT, but there might be sub-exponential or almost-polynomial algorithms, and I think "brute force only" has to exclude some of those.